# backup of old Mac, but tar says: Error exit delayed from previous errors

Tags: mac, backup, tar

I try to backup an old Mac OS X Tiger 10.4 before upgrading it to 10.6. All the files to be backed up are located within the `/Users/Johndoe` folder.

```
cd /tmp
sudo tar cvpf backup.tar /Users/Johndoe
```

However the tar command aborts the operation and says:

```
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

The homedir is about 30 Gb and there is about 100 Gb available space. I see no errors in the console output.

How can I backup this old Mac?  Should I use something else than tar?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I did not see any errors.

```
sudo cp -R -p -v /Users/Johndoe /Volumes/MyExternalBackupDisk/BackupJohndoe
```